# Sub select com COUNT e SUM

Tags: sql, postgresql

Possuo a seguinte *query*:

```
SELECT 
    s1.suprimento, 
    e1.numeroserie, 
    s1.capacidade, 
    e1.numeronotafiscal, 
    e1.valorunitario, 
    e1.datanotafiscal
FROM 
    public.estoque e1, 
    public.suprimento s1,
    public.fornecedor 
WHERE
    e1.datanotafiscal is not null and
    s1.codigo = e1.codigosuprimento and 
    e1.codigofornecedor = public.fornecedor.codigo and 
    e1.numeronotafiscal = '19255'
ORDER BY 
    e1.datanotafiscal desc,s1.suprimento
```

Onde obtenho o seguinte retorno:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como poderia fazer um *count* para retornar a quantidade de cada suprimento desse retorno, e soma dos valor unitários de cada item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa remover o `e1.numeroserie` da consulta (já que ele é único) e agrupar pelas demais colunas:

```
SELECT 
    s1.suprimento,
    s1.capacidade, 
    e1.numeronotafiscal, 
    e1.valorunitario, /*sum(e1.valorunitario) -- substituir consulta do valorunitario caso queira a soma*/
    count(*) as total
FROM 
    public.estoque e1, 
    public.suprimento s1,
    public.fornecedor 
WHERE 
    e1.datanotafiscal is not null and
    s1.codigo = e1.codigosuprimento and 
    e1.codigofornecedor = public.fornecedor.codigo and 
    e1.numeronotafiscal = '19255'
GROUP BY
    s1.suprimento, 
    s1.capacidade, 
    e1.numeronotafiscal, 
    e1.valorunitario, /*remover do group by caso queira soma dos valores*/
    e1.datanotafiscal
ORDER BY 
    e1.datanotafiscal desc,s1.suprimento
```

Exemplo online [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/20173/4)

**Detalhe**:

O valor unitário é o mesmo no retorno, não entendei porque você precisa da "soma dos valor unitários de cada item".

Comment: Eu estava fazendo uma solução aqui mas como você já havia respondido exatamente o mesmo que eu iria falar, apenas acrescentei o link de um sqlfiddle  a sua resposta.